# Can any one please let me know Free RESTful services to learn?

Tags: rest

I have gone through searching free api's.

I found this. http://api.rottentomatoes.com which is useful for me to learn..

But the only thing, it has all GET Methods only.. It would be great if someone could suggest the free api which has all Method POST, GET, DELETE, PUT. So that it would be useful for me.

Thanks

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but considering how non-restful a lot of public APIs that claim to be REST are you are probably better studying the theory rather than studying public APIs. The Web itself is the ultimate RESTful API, so just look at how HTTP is designed to work.

Comment: I am trying to arrive the webservice testing in Soapui.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. If you are just looking for an API to learn how to use SoapUI you could try the Twitter one. It is not particularly RESTful but it is better than the RottenTomatoes one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the previous comment are true. Not even Twitter is RESTful.

My suggestion would be to search for a REST cookbook. http://restcookbook.com and read the RFC 2616. The problem is that the majority of "REST" APIs don't even know what HATEOS is. Read the article from Martin Fowler about the Richardson Maturity Model.
http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge directory of web APIs, including a [list of REST APIs](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?protocol=REST), at [programmable web](http://www.programmableweb.com). I haven't read them all to see which ones are true to the principles of REST, but at least there are plenty to choose from!

Comment: This is a bad source because there so many APIs that there is no chance of finding a true REST API. 
Its a needle in a haystack search.